Best practice: set up comint-interpreter loop with colours and tool-tips included added to output
I want to have the output of my interpreter/REPL prettified by the comint-mode buffer in which I'm running it.  I can adjust the interpreter output to include whatever textual markup I want (e.g., I might enclose pieces of text in HTML style tags à la <color=red>actual output</color>).  Given the "right" output format, what combination of comint-preoutput-filter-functions and friends should I then use to get certain substrings coloured appropriately (want three different colours), and to have certain substrings associated with tooltips (text for which the interpreter also provides)?
I'm worried by the way output that is fed to pre-output filters can get split at awkward places (right in the middle of the <color=red> string, maybe).  I have a solution of sorts that uses a pre-output filter to copy text into a buffer that can wait for output to be well-formed, but the comint output is then very jerky and the output-action comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom doesn't work reliably.  (This worked better in emacs 27, but I'm now on emacs 29.4.)
Advice gratefully received.

If your comint-output-filter-functions contains ansi-color-process-output then you might consider simply making your process output (or optionally output) ansi colour escape codes -- and then it'll be coloured in a regular terminal as well, which is nice.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

I'm worried by the way output that is fed to pre-output filters can get split at awkward places

Yeah, that's a pain.  I can only suggest examining the standard output filters to see how they handle it.
For the tool-tips, though, I don't see why you couldn't add the text properties in a post-processing step, potentially leaving it until the output has completed and you can perform a single pass over the whole thing.  I assume the user isn't likely to be interacting with the text in that way mid-output?

Thanks!  This "process it all in one step" is certainly tempting, and it's reassuring to have someone tell me it's reasonable. When people run in TERMs that support it, we already emit the ANSI colours, and I feel better about also emitting tooltips in that sort of way.  I would presumably lose the ability to let people pick their own colours for each option (my existing code maps the markup to mode-specific faces that can be customised).

People can (customize-group "ansi-colors") -- which will affect them in all contexts in Emacs.

Did not know that!  Thanks again

Other food for thought is C-h v comint-osc-handlers via which you could possibly use an entirely custom OSC code to supply your tool tips in a similar manner to how the window title and hyperlink OSC handlers must be receiving fairly arbitrary text.  That might be a convenient way to piggy-back onto a system which (I assume) already copes with the arbitrariness of buffered output boundaries.

Yeah, that looks like great tech for the application; thanks!
